# OneNote API returns incorrect data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

Since yesterday the OneNote API has displayed unusual behavior, simple calls are returning the incorrect notebook `name` or `displayname`.

For example, calls to  `https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/me/notes/notebooks` returns an old notebook `name` that has since been renamed.

More complex filtering calls are completely confused when filtering by `parentNotebook/name`

```
Date: Mon, 20 Nov 2017 16:11:00 GMT

X-CorrelationId: 3af6f882-c15c-4871-928f-d04c9bfabca7

id: 1-e1ab8fa1-b2cd-433a-a346-5a1a0c775264
name: "Template2-WE"
links:oneNoteWebUrl:href:https://*************/Documents/Notebooks/TemplatePages-WE
```

Comment: Could you provide the actual output? The `CorrelationId` is helpful since the community has no mechanism to look them up.

Comment: Providing a CorrelationId and a Timestamp would definitely be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to a known limitation of OneNote. If you rename a OneNote notebook in the OneNote Client, the rename is only effective in the clients - if you open OneDrive/SharePoint and look at your notebook, you will see (Notebooks are folders) the folder still has the old name. The API only sees the folder name, which in this case is the "old" incorrect name.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Rename-a-notebook-in-OneNote-Online-d75e88d2-ef77-43eb-a870-0abe89c1a036

If you follow these instructions and rename your notebook in the online portal, the API should see these changes.

Comment: Hi Jorge. This is a definite change in normal behaviour on my end with no change to my scripts.   A workaround for me at present is to filter on parentNotebook/links/oneNoteWebUrl/href instead of my usual parentNotebook/name.  I'll post an example as soon as I can

Comment: The behavior I described means that the API will always give you the same name as the URL - is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: Not at present. The template notebook I have in the example above opens everywhere with the name "TemplatePages-WE" (and is visible as this) but any API call that responds with this notebook gives it the name "Template2-WE". I've tried to rename it online and on OneNote for mac but no change.

Comment: OK. My problem was how I was creating the notebooks, this was being done outside of the OneNote API (for the last 18 months), fine up to now but not working for the last few days. Using the create notebook API does indeed fix this issue. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just for curiosity - how were you creating notebooks?

Comment: Using WebDAV to copy an empty notebook into sharepoint, uploading the content of an archived notebook into the dummy notebook and then using the onedrive API to rename the notebook.